# Iterator Java Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list

I am creating a linked list in Java not using the Java API Linked List class. This is creating a calculator that displays the polynomial and is meant to store data in a linked list. The polynomials are meant to be added to the head of the list and then displayed in order of size (but this doesn't work yet). The part I am struggling with is the addTerm method - as this is supposed to iterate through the list add to the head of the list. I am not new to Java, but I have only basic knowledge. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.soap.Node;

public class PolyData implements Polynomial {

private static class Node{

    Node next;
    public Term term;

}
private static Node head; 

public  Iterator<Term> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return new LinkedList(head);
   }

public static void insertAtHead(Term term) {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.term = term;
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

public static void insertAfter(Term term, Node insertPoint) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.term = term;
    newNode.next = insertPoint.next;
    insertPoint.next = newNode;
}

@Override
public  void addTerm(Term term) {
   Iterator<Term> iter = LinkedList.iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
       Node newNode = new Node();
       newNode.term = term;
       newNode.next = head;
       head = newNode;
   }
}





public void addPoly(Polynomial poly) {
    //not implemented
}

@Override
public void multiplyByPoly(Polynomial poly) {
    //not implemented
}





public static class LinkedList implements Iterator<Term> {

    private Node current;
    private LinkedList(Node start) {current=start;}

    public static  Iterator<Term> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new LinkedList(head);
        }



    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {return (current != null);}

    @Override
    public Term next() {
          Term result = current.term;
          current = current.next;
          return result;
     }
     @Override
     public void remove() {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }


}

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: public static  Iterator<Term> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new LinkedList(head);
        } Where is the declaration of head?

Comment: @efekctive its private static Node head;

Comment: It should not be static. Otherwise it would be shared by all lists. Second the code you post should compile or have all the pieces to look at

Comment: "The part I am struggling with is the addTerm method" - can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: that method adds a new term for each term in the list. So it ends up adding N every time. I think

Comment: @Joe C yes sorry it iterates through the list adds a new term to the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public  void addTerm(Term term) {
   Iterator<Term> iter = LinkedList.iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
       Node newNode = new Node();
       newNode.term = term;
       newNode.next = head;
       head = newNode;
   }
}
```

if polynomial is x^2 + x + 1 then after inserting all terms it will end up with

x^2 (head) + x (first insertion has one element in list) + 2 (when you insert 1 there are two elements in the list so it is inserted twice)